# Размер шрифта у динамически созданного TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textview

Если указать в xml **android:textSize="10sp"**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Тестовое сообщение"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
/>
```

Шрифт одного размера получается, а если программно создать TextView и задать размер шрифта

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
```

размер получается другой (больше чем через xml).

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
```

вместо "10" лучше использовать ресурс: `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textSize)`

Comment: Результат такой же. Спасибо.

Comment: У меня сработало так: .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

Comment: 14 на других `dpi` будет выглядеть другим. Получится не адапативная вёрстка.

Comment: "Результат такой же" - это работает или нет?)

Comment: ваш вариант не работает, т.е. все также как у меня было раньше)
"10" я так, для примера же писал) На самом деле у меня должно быть 14sp)) + за ответ)

Comment: Посмотрите, я добавил вариант. В таком у меня работает

Comment: А почему вы в примере делите на scaledDensity?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89110/discussion-between-duosduo-and-jarvis-j).